# Excel Javascript API is not available after redirecting to different domain page

Tags: javascript, excel, api

I have an Office Task Pane add-in for Excel 2016 implemented using Excel Javascript API. It represents a subset of our application features in Excel. The plan is to release it in Office Store. Each our customer has its own production environment in separate domain hosting our application. Since I can only define one SourceLocation element in add-in manifest file, but there are many application instances which add-in should be able to access, I have implemented a simple ASP.NET MVC web page hosted in Windows Azure, where an user is prompted to enter his company name and credentials. Then I build an URL based on user input and redirect to his domain where our application is hosted. After redirect, customer's add-in is displayed correctly, but Excel API is not available anymore. Office.initialize is triggered, but Office.context.requirements set is empty and Excel object is undefined. I tried iframe too, but nothing helps. On ASP.NET web page specified in manifest file Excel API is loaded. It seems that it disappears after redirect only. Is anyone familiar with such issue, it is possible at all to make a redirect in Office add-in?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the app domains in your manifest file? Adding something like this directly under the `OfficeApp` element should allow you to redirect to any page under that domain and still have access to the `Excel` object. (This one is set to `localhost` as I'm still developing my add-in.)

`<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://localhost</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the problem. URL parameter _host_Info had to be passed from one page to another. This parameter is set by Excel on add-in startup, but when you do redirect without passing it, web page cannot detect where it is hosted and therefore doesn't load Excel API.
More info about host info here:
http://simonjaeger.com/where-am-i-detecting-the-office-host-in-office-add-ins/